# How can I return a text file with exact positioning?

Tags: python, django, text, file-io

I'm creating a text file response with Django. I'm implementing it the normal way with a template file.

```
def create_file(request):
    ... create context ...

    result = render_to_string('template.txt', context_dict)
    response = HttpResponse(result, mimetype='text/plain')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file.txt'
    return response
```

The text file response is unique though, in that each character in the file must be positioned exactly. So every character in the file, including whitespaces is placed deliberately. This presents a problem for lines with variables on them that have unspecified length. So lets say we have 2 variables that are strings and are on the same line in the template.

```
{{variable1}}   {{variable2}}
```

And variable2 must appear in column 5 of the text file. How can I specify an exact position for variable2 if I don't know how many spaces variable1 takes up? Alternatively, am I just going about this totally wrong? Might it be easier to ditch the template altogether and create the text response entirely in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suggested, I would do this in the view.

For the example you gave, you can use [`string.ljust`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/string.html?highlight=format#string.ljust) to left justify a string, padding with spaces as needed.

```
>>> from string import ljust
>>> variable1 = "v1"
>>> variable2 = "v2"
>>> ljust(variable1, 4)
'v1  '
>>> line = "%s%s" % (ljust(variable1, 4), variable2)
'v1  v2'
```

Alternatively, as Elf and ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ pointed out in the comments, you can use `%-formatting`

```
>>> from string import ljust
>>> variable1 = "v1"
>>> variable2 = "v2"
>>> line = "%-4s%s" % (variable1, variable2)
'v1  v2'
```

Using `.4` to truncate `variable1` to 4 characters:

```
>>> variable1 = "12345"
>>> variable2 = "v2"
>>> line = "%-4s.4%s" % (variable1, variable2)
'v1  v2'
```

Comment: And right-justification is easier.  ("%06s" % variable1) will put 6 - len spaces to the left of the string.  (It will not, however, truncate to 6 characters if that's needed.)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Using ljust looks much more promising than templates. Now I'll need to think of a code structure to handle each case for the lines I'm creating (62 to be exact :-( )

Comment: You'd have to do that anyway, no?  Even if Templates did what you wanted, you'd still have to describe each line in exacting detail, in much the same way that a web page describes each DIV, SPAN, and TABLE/TR/TD in exacting detail.  Describe the structure, then write code to merge it and your data.  Then write code to make the structures pluggable.

Comment: Oh absolutely. In fact this method will be easier since I can implement it with a loop instead of explicitly laying out each line.

Comment: @Elf: to left-justify 6 chars at the *most*, you need `"%-6.6s" % variable`), and for right-justification you need `"%6.6s" % variable`). "%06s" fills with zeroes.

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ -- nice! I didn't know about `-6` for left justification or `.6` to truncate. For Python >= 2.6, the new string formatting is another option.

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ -- Awesome, thank you.  I really could have used that answer when I faced Buken's problem last year, writing code to spit out invoices for the warehouse team.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it would be easier to create the response entirely within the view.  Templates are just a convenient plug-in for rendering structured text with a static scaffold, but it sounds to me like your structure is in the layout and not the scaffold.

I would, indeed, do this by creating my own little templating engine to handle this one special case.  There are plenty of examples of Django doing this, to spit out CSV, PDF, and even images generated by the Django applications.

Answer (score 2):

The (on the way to become obsolete) `sprintf`-like `%` formatting has the following capabilities:

```
 "%6.6s" % variable # right-justify at most 6 characters prefixing spaces as needed
 "%-6.6s" % variable # left-justify at most 6 characters appending spaces as needed
 "%-*.*s" % (width, width, variable) # left-justify at most width characters
```

However, I don't know how your templating mechanism is implemented and whether it can use `%` formatting.